# Migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio and use Gradle instead of ant

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I migrated an Android project from Eclipse to Android Studio. I have the project in Android Studio but I would like to use "Gradle" instead of ant as the build system.

What's the best way to make this conversion?

Comment: Just import your project with the Import Project wizard and it should do everything automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't automatic for you? It was for me; which seems a little odd, but I do realize that Android projects were formerly built with ant. So... here's a link to a post that should help you migrate from ant to gradle: [Migrate from Ant to Gradle](https://coderwall.com/p/npki6q/migrate-existing-android-project-to-gradle)